# Xamarin Tabhost - overlapped tab content

Tags: xamarin, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I created a tabbed application using TabHost widget, from Xamarin.

When I am changing the tabs, they are overlapping.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRbbi.jpg

This is the layout for the main page.
I have the tabs at the buttom of the screen and the content of the tabs above.
The tabs are created dynamically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/actualtabcontent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tabContainer"/>
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tabContainer" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@color/fullOpacityBlack">
      <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                   android:orientation="horizontal"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="90dp"
                   android:layout_weight="0"
                   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                   android:background="@color/fullOpacityBlack" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
      </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I managed to solve it by adding background on every tab layout